# Toolbar causing app to crash

Tags: android, layout

hope you can help.

I am working through a tutorial but one of the lines is making the app crash, if I leave it in the app crashes but if I take it out the app runs, the problem is, I need the menu bar in the app.

This is the line

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This is the entire code of the onCreate method

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.reminders_list_view);
    mListView.setDivider(null);
    mDbAdapter = new RemindersDbAdapter(this);
    mDbAdapter.open();
    Cursor cursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAllReminders();

    String[] from = new String[]{
            RemindersDbAdapter.COL_CONTENT
    };

    int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.row_text
    };
    mCursorAdapter = new RemindersSimpleCursorAdapter(RemindersActivity.this,R.layout.reminders_row,cursor,from,to,0);

    mListView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_reminders, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_new:
        //create new Reminder
            Log.d(getLocalClassName(), "create new Reminder");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_exit:
            finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

and this is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".RemindersActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_reminders"/>
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong. I don't understand enough about android yet to figure out what is causing this but hopefully someone has encountered this before or knows what to do to help. I would really like to move on with the tutorial

Thank you, hope you understand the question.

Comment: could you  please post the logcat too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

below

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);
```

E.g:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

> findViewById() returns a View if it exists in the layout you provided
>   in setContentView(), otherwise it returns null and that's what
>   happening to you.
>
> If you setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders);
>   and then call findViewById(R.id.toolbar); it will return a View which
>   is your layout, But if you call findViewById(R.id.toolbar); before
>   setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminders); it will return null since
>   there is no view attached to your activity.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe it was so simple and I didn't try that!

Comment: Yes thank you and thank you for explaining it aswell, have a better understanding now of how it works :)

Comment: @Cleave Happy to help you. :-)